# How to optimize a function that takes arrays as arguments

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to use optimize.curve_fit function with the function:

```
def nlorentz(x,X0,G):
# This function calculates the sum of n = len(X0) lorentzians.
s = 0
for i in range(len(X0)):
    s += lorentz(x,X0[i],G[i])
return s
```

Where X0 and G are arrays.

I have a list of guesses:

```
gG = [1,2]
gX0 = [1.2,3]
```

Then I want ot optimize the function for every value of X0:

```
p,cov = curve_fit(nlorentz,x,y,p0=[gX0,gG])
```

So that the desired result is:

```
p = [optimized_X0, optimized_G]
```

Where both optimized_X0 and optimized_G are arrays.

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: nlorentz() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I don't know if there is a way to do this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: find documentation for `curve_fit`  and check what function it needs. It seeems it needs  function which gets5 arguments - `nlorentz(a,b,c,d,e)` - but you have function which gets only 3 arguments - `nlorentz(x,X0,G)`.

Comment: BTW: you can always add two arguments with default value `def nlorentz(x,X0,G, d=None, e=None):`.